# Does a design rationale exist for the PHP-Style Nested Webform pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, webforms

I'm working on an implementation of a webform decoder and am looking to support the *nested webform* pattern employed by PHP and Ruby/Rails (possibly amongst others).

PHP: `parse_str()`; Ruby: `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query()`

I've noticed some inconsistencies, for example (behaviour is the same in both languages):

```
foo=One&foo=Two
=> {'foo':'Two'}

foo[][bar]=One&foo[][bar]=Two
=> {"foo":[{"bar":"One"},{"bar":"Two"}]}
```

Here identical keys are discarded if at the top-level, but respected if at they exist lower down.

Is the rationale behind this design documented anywhere? Was the Ruby/Rails approach based on the PHP design (or vice-verca)?

Comment: I would imagine that you would find the logic for each behavior in the language specifications.  There are differences because they are two different programming languages.  Asking "why did some language designer make some design decision" is not a meaningful question, unless it is directed at the language designer himself.  In general, PHP and Ruby are very different languages in both syntax and philosophy.  PHP defies logic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the differences in syntax and philosophy are irrelevant for the purposes of this question: their handling of webforms (in terms of map, array and string primitives) they are remarkably similar. I'd like to know why.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *'why did some language designer make some design decision' is not a meaningful question* —isn't that the purpose of this site?

Comment: As the rationale is not contained within the language specification nor documentation of either language, I'd imagine such that it exists is likely be buried within public or possibly private discussion on potentially multiple forums. I had—perhaps misguidedly—hoped that a site dedicated to software engineering might encourage the participation of the types of people who likely frequent such forums and would have such a reference to hand (as I do for many arcane details for my chosen language). Or at least have some nugget on the whys of what is to me at this time a meaningful subject.

Comment: One purpose of this site is to answer questions about software design. But we cannot tell you why one language or framework designer made one choice and another made a different choice. We would be guessing. Unless, of course, the language designers just popped in to answer the question. A question that only specific people can answer isn't a good fit.

Comment: @ThomasOwens This isn't a case of one language designer making one choice and another making a different choice—apparently two (I assume) 'language designers' (was possibly contributions) made the same choice—despite the differences between the languages—that I can't rightly say is not a coincidence. Just as one person may have made the decision does not mean that he/she alone knows the rationale for that decision.

Comment: The point still stands - we can't tell you why anyone made a design decision that they chose to make. We would be guessing. We don't do this kind of thing here.

Comment: @ThomasOwens 'We' don't include language designers/project leads that would make/participate in this type of decision in a Software Engineering forum?

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for the language designer responsible for the original decision, just for some rationale as to why this convention seems to be a prevailing one. Please look at my original motivation for asking this question.

Comment: @ThomasOwens *'answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise'* —I'm only looking for facts, [particularly] references, or specific expertise. I'm not sure what opinions folks have that would be at all relevant to the question.

Comment: If you have a problem, please take it to Meta. But we cannot answer this question here. Our speculation on what these language designers were thinking would be opinions.

Comment: The most likely possibility is that one copied the technique from the other.  That happens a lot in software development.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suspect that might be the case, but I'd like to know if that was a conscious decision (i.e. is documented somewhere).

Comment: @rgchris, this is a Q/A site, not a forum. Just wanted to point that out so that you don't think we're being rude here, its just that this site is specifically for generally answerable questions, which do not require a SPECIFIC person (in this case a language designer) to answer.

Comment: @Graham I don't consider this a question that only a specific person could answer: I'd posit that anyone that follows language development—those in particular—has the potential to offer insight. I don't develop the language I primarily use, but have read extensively of the decisions that were made to make it so. Perhaps this isn't the norm amongst software engineers (yikes!).

Comment: Just FYI—I do have a meta question open on this post: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8714/94356

Comment: I disagree with the hold. Almost any question of the form “what is the rationale for design pattern X” could conceivably get a biased, opinionated reply, but I would see that asthe fault of the reply-er. The phrasing, “Is the rationale behind this design documented anywhere?“ seems to alliw for fact-based answers, “yes, here it is...” or, “not that I could find”

Comment: Rub that cat in one direction, it purrs. Rub it the other way, you get clawed. Porcupine... Don't rub.

Comment: I honestly know nothing about what you are working with, but if your question is basically that you noticed that hierarchical structures can have duplicated keys as long as there is a parent node between them, then that has nothing to do with programming language. For example, there can be google.com and google.uk, but you can't have two .coms or .uks. Apologies if I misunderstood what you are asking.

Comment: @nocomprende I'd noticed one instance of strange behaviour in an implementation of a design pattern that was common between two very different platforms and as a pattern I'm hoping to support, was looking for an explanation. While the manner of the question has an inevitable research quality to it, it's still very much a [past-tense] decision of the type addressed on this site. I could have asked 'what should I do in these two cases?', but I know in advance I'm likely going to mimic this behaviour and am looking for the rationale behind it.